# How to pass value from one table to mapping variable or mapping expression?

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I get value from exchange rate table to mapping expression (variable) to count exchange rates.

I have a mapping that use one src table to count US$ to CHF - for this I need another dict table. Dict table stores exchange rates for expression used by mapping. I need to lookup a value - exchange_rate from dict table and store it and then use for calculations - just like this 100US$ x EXCH_RATE = x CHF.
How to solve this issue?

Comment: Use a Lookup Transformation, perhaps? Please show what you've tried so far and where your problem is, I'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to create WF variable - WF Manager->VARIABLE TAB->add new variable
and then you have to options either you can threat it as MAX/MIN variable which value will be stored into REPO via IS (each run can change the value of it) o reset it for each run (Pre & Post session variable need to be sets) or simple add it to PARAM file with specific value.